# Integrate cloudinary_js with ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, npm, ember-cli, cloudinary

I am working on my first ember application using Ember-cli

Here i want to add feature of image-upload using cloudinary_js

Referring this [link](http://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_image_uploads_from_the_browser_to_the_cloud_with_jquery)

Image Model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
var attr = DS.attr;

export default DS.Model.extend({
  imageUrl:         attr('string'),
  thumbImageUrl:    attr('string'),
  standardImageUrl: attr('string'),
  favourite:        attr('string'),
  order:            attr('number')
});
```

I have already added the required js files using bower and listed them in Brocfile.js

```
app.import('vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js');
app.import('vendor/jquery.iframe-transport/jquery.iframe-transport.js');
app.import('vendor/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js');
app.import('vendor/cloudinary_js/js/jquery.cloudinary.js');
```

Added file field as component:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: "input",
  type: "file",
  accept: "image/*",
  class: "cloudinary-fileupload",
  dataCloudinaryField: "image_id",
  attributeBindings: [ "name", "type", "value", "class"],
  change: function() {
  }
});
```

Here am stuck with, where to specify the config of cloudinary (cloud name and api key)?

Can anyone please help me with the detailed steps of cloudinary integration with ember using ember-cli.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to have an initializer that sets the **cloud_name** and **api_key** properties. I would put this code in *app/initializers/cloudinary.js*.

```
export default {
  name: 'cloudinary',

  initialize: function() {
    $.cloudinary.config({
      cloud_name: 'MYCLOUD',
      api_key:    'MYKEY'
    });
  }
};
```

I wrote a detailed blog post on [how to integrate cloudinary_js and Ember](http://beerlington.com/blog/2014/07/13/direct-image-uploads-with-emberjs-and-cloudinary/) a few days ago. There's an [example app](https://github.com/beerlington/cats-ui) that uses ember-cli and shows how to configure Cloudinary and everything you'd need to get it up and running. There are some tricky parts to getting the whole thing working, so I'd recommend checking that out if you get tripped up after the config setup right.